# I assembled my computer and it won't boot even though the power seems to be flowing in

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply

my name's Marc, I'm a computer enthusiast and I recently purchased components for a decent configuration willing to assemble it myself. So I did that, everything fit together and I was happy but when I plugged the newly assembled beast to the screen and pressed the Power button I was quickly disappointed.

All the LEDs and fans started correctly but nothing appeared on the screen. The computer seems to be trying to boot for like 15 seconds and then shuts down and restarts indefinitely. I tried to plug on the screen on the DVI port of the motheboard (instead of the Display port of the graphical card) but still nothing happened, I never could access the BIOS or anything on the screen.

I verified all the connections I made and tried to boot with the simplest configuration possible (Power supply + motherboard + CPU + RAM) with the exact same symptoms: nothing ever appeared on my screen. I did the test with another Power Supply (which is working fine on another computer) with the same result.

I could not test the CPU or RAM individually as they are not compatible with any of the stuff that me or my roommates owe. I kind of suspect the motherboard as the number of components makes it more likely that one of them is defective but I don't know what tests I can perform from home. I do own a multimeter that I used to check some of the voltages provided by the Power Supply, maybe there are some components on the motherboard I can test with the VOM?

The components I bought are the following :

- CPU: Intel Core i5-6600K (3.5 GHz)
- Motherboard: Gigabyte Z170-HD3P
- RAM: DDR4 G.Skill Aegis, 16 GB, 2133 MHz, CAS 15
- Graphical card: KFA2 GeForce GTX 1070 EX, 8 GB
- Power Supply: Be Quiet ! System Power 8, 600W
- Kingston V300, 120 GB, SATA III
- Seagate BarraCuda, 1 TB

I checked beforehand that everything was compatible so I assume they are but maybe they actually aren't?

Anyway as you can see I am a bit lost right now, the worst case scenario is I go to a store and have them assemble it for me (which I don't think will change a thing) and once they see it doesn't work they perform tests but this costs more than 100€ so if there is a way I can do the tests myself that would be great!

Thanks in advance, if I forgot any relevant information feel free to ask!

Marc.

Comment: Any beep codes emitted by the mobo?

Comment: Nope, not any beep :(

Comment: What are the warranty laws/return policies in your country like? I would guess France or Quebec but have no idea about either of those. But had i ordered it online, i would simply send the mobo back and have them send me a new one. If any of those key components was faulty it should beep. If you can maybe try the VGA on the motherboard for good measure.

Comment: Possible dumb question, the system speaker is plugged onto the motherboard to hear the beep codes? I've been down that road before...

Comment: @DrZoo Doesn't the mobo own a mini builtin speaker?

Comment: @marcbizot Also Marc do you have any working RAM stick from another computer that you could use instead of the one you currently use? Could worth the shot

Comment: Yeah I'm from France, I can send the products back but they asked me to perform tests to be sure it was the mobo. I'll try one last time with th speakers and will send it back

Comment: You don't have to connect any "speaker" to produce beep codes with a modern mobo.  There should be a buzzer (a black cylinder about 0.5" tall, 0.5" diameter, with a small hole on top) installed on the mobo.  The silkscreen may actually identify it as "BUZZER".  If there are no beeps at all, then the CPU and/or mobo are suspect, since you seem to have absolved the PSU.

Comment: @sawdust I'm not sure about that. I have a pretty modern board and the speaker is not built in. Looking at the manual for this motherboard, confirms that a speaker is not built-in. Per the manual for the Front Panel Header, it says *SPEAK - Connects to the speaker on the chassis front panel. The system reports
system startup status by issuing a beep code. One single short beep
will be heard if no problem is detected at system startup. (page 16)* So the fact that the user is hearing no beeps, means it is not plugged in.

Comment: Here is an image of the [motherboard](http://pclab.pl/zdjecia/artykuly/opson/Plyty_Z170/Gigabyte_Z170-HD3P/_MG_1175b.jpg). You plug the speaker onto the orange section of the F_PANEL in the very bottom right hand corner of the board.